# Excel sort values by date and time

Tags: excel, sorting

I have 5 columns with values (and many rows).  First column is timestamp in the format dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.000
The last three zeros indicate miliseconds, e.g.  09.12.2021 22:00:34.343

We use this kind of date format (day first before month).

If I try to sort them in Excel , they get sorted alfabetically and not chronologically.

For the values below

```
23.10.2021 20:59:47.066

23.10.2021 21:07:17.061

23.10.2021 21:17:17.082

23.10.2021 23:42:18.008

23.11.2021 11:11:00.005

23.11.2021 11:21:00.096

24.10.2021 00:32:18.052

24.11.2021 16:42:14.046
```

I need to get

```
23.10.2021 20:59:47.066

23.10.2021 21:07:17.061

23.10.2021 21:17:17.082

23.10.2021 23:42:18.008

**24.10.2021 00:32:18.052**

23.11.2021 11:11:00.005

23.11.2021 11:21:00.096

24.11.2021 16:42:14.046
```

What workaround is for this?

Comment: Are you sure these are dates and times and not strings?

Comment: i get the timestamps from a text file so they are strings, representind date and time

Answer (score 1):

**One solution** (if the Timestamps must remain as string values):
Add a helper column that converts the string values to sort-able date/time values. The formula for that would be:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,10),".","/"))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,12))
```

Note:
a) The above is of course converts the value at cell A1
b) It assume the format is always dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.nnn

**Sample Result** (sorted on column B)
[image]
In case you’re wondering, the `Number Format` for `Column B` is `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.000`

Answer (score 1):

To convert the strings to "real dates" which can be sorted in date/time order, you can use this formula to create a *Helper* column

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,4,2), LEFT(A1,2)) + TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,12))
```

This formula will work independently of the Windows Regional Settings on the computer.  It obviously assumes the source data is DMY, but will convert the string to a real date even if the WRS on the target compute is something else.

**Original Data**
[image]

**Sorted**
[image]

*The helper column can be hidden, or deleted after the sorting is done*

Comment: it is not working  for me

Comment: @fjohn As you can see from the screenshots, it works here.  I suspect there is either an issue with your data which I did not appreciate from your example, or you have not properly applied the solution I showed.